# Can I remotely access an iPhone from a computer overseas?

Tags: iphone

I'm in England and have no Apple products.

My mom's in North America. We both have Internet. She's unskilled, but having difficulties, with iPhone that I'd like to access remotely from my Windows laptop. 
Can I?

Comment: Did you consider teamviever app

Comment: @Buscar웃 No; I didn't know about it! Thanks for introducing me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the TeamViewer app.

Both side have to have it (you and your Mom).

You would download the version for your PC

while your Mom can use the iPhone version.

[image]

Here is the [download site](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/download/ios/) for all devices and OS.

Once installed your mom has to share her Login and the password with you.

Comment: Can Windows PCs use this? I just tried to download it, but https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/teamviewer/id692035811 states "This app is only available on the App Store for iOS devices."

Comment: for windows version go here https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/download/windows/